# Scrapyd приостановка и продолжение парсинга

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

Насколько мне известно в документации к Scrapyd не описано, как приостанавливать и возобновлять работу краулера. 
В обычном Scrapy  это делается без проблем следующей командой:

scrapy crawl myspider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1

Как добиться того же результата в  Scrapyd?